# How to install python-uno package in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: python

I got the following error while installing python-uno:

```
Package python-uno is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libreoffice-script-provider-python

E: Package 'python-uno' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: What do u want to install exactly?

Comment: I have install python-uno package

Answer (score -1, accepted):

open the terminal and run the following command...

sudo apt-get install libreoffice python-genshi python-cairo python-lxml python-setuptools
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-script-provider-python

easy_install uno

Comment: What is `easy_install`?  Where does that come from?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is asking for libreoffice-script-provider-python,

```
 sudo apt-get install libreoffice-script-provider-python
```

This will install python3-uno package, and the interface for LO to use UNO.

Comment: Consider accepting as solution if this helps..it must help!!..tick √ below downvote and upvote to mark it green so as to mark this thread as solved